# Filling DatagridView cells after validating first row in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a DataGridView of 4-5 columns.
The DataGridView is Editable.
When I enter a value in the Reference Column then immediately it will fill the
 other values in the others cells from mysql database.
But when I go to the next row and I want to add another value in the reference 
cell and then it will fill the other like the first one, it didn't do it...
This is what I tried....

```
private void TAB_Credit_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (TAB_Credit.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Reference")
    {

         string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM tb_ajout_articles 
                            WHERE Reference=@ref";
         MySqlDataAdapter sa = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdText, MyConnexion);
         sa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ref", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =
         TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Reference"].Value.ToString();

         DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
         sa.Fill(dt);

         if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
         {
             TXT_Stock.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Quantite"].ToString();
             //double value = (double)TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantite"].Value * (double)TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Prix_Unitaire"].Value;

             TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Designation"].Value = dt.Rows[0]["Designation"].ToString();
             TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantite"].Value = dt.Rows[0]["Quantite"].ToString();
             TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Prix_Unitaire"].Value = dt.Rows[0]["Prix_Unitaire"].ToString();
             TAB_Credit["Total", e.RowIndex].Value = 
               Convert.ToString(
               Convert.ToInt32(TAB_Credit["Quantite", e.RowIndex].Value) * 
               Convert.ToInt32(TAB_Credit["Prix_Unitaire", e.RowIndex].Value));
               //TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = value.ToString();

             TXT_Brut.Text = TAB_Credit["Total", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

         }
     }
     if (TAB_Credit.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)
     {
         if (Convert.ToInt32(TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantite"].Value) > Convert.ToInt32(TXT_Stock.Text))
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Stock finished");
             TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantite"].Value = dt.Rows[0]["Quantite"].ToString();

         }
         else
         {
             TAB_Credit["Total", e.RowIndex].Value = 
                   Convert.ToString(
                   Convert.ToInt32(TAB_Credit["Quantite", e.RowIndex].Value) * 
                   Convert.ToInt32(TAB_Credit["Prix_Unitaire", e.RowIndex].Value));
             TXT_Brut.Text = TAB_Credit["Total", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sure if you stepped through with the debugger you can find a reason. Have you tried it?

Comment: using Debugger.break(); ?

Comment: You could, but I always forget to remove it. Just press F9 on the line you want to break on.

Comment: Do you think it is because of the event ? CellValueChanged ? Or I must use CellEndEdit ?

Comment: I don't know. I would debug it, step through the code, view the variable values and observe the execution path. I can't see anything wrong with the code just by looking at it.

Comment: It only debug on the first row when I go to the second row the debug doesn't worked

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help if you don't know how to do basic debugging.

Comment: I did a debugging...I put F9 in the CellValueChanged event , and the debug work when I insert in the first row when I go to the second row the debug is not showing up

Comment: Debugging allows you to inspect variable values, see if conditions pass `if` statements, etc, etc. Just breaking on a line does nothing, this is giving you the opportunity to inspect things.

Comment: I found the problem it is because of :  `if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)`